# In Blender 2.8 where did the Lock frame selection to range button go?

Tags: interface

Where is the "Don't allow frame to be selected with mouse outside of frame range" button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the timeline and click playback then tick the limit playhead to frame range [image: "tick the limit playhead to frame range]